# Cut a String (java)

Tags: java, string, split, ftp

I would like to cut my string `"ftp://user:password@ftp.domain.com:21"` to have each article in a string

in other words, I want to have:

```
String ftp = "ftp.domain.com"

String user = "user"

String password = "password"

String port = "21"
```

This code that works but it's a little dirty, right?

```
String fullFtpAdress = "ftp://user:password@ftp.domain.com:21";
fullFtpAdress = fullFtpAdress.substring(6);
String[] parts1 = fullFtpAdress.split(":",2);
String user = parts1[0];
String[] parts2 = parts1[1].split("@");
String password = parts2[0];
String[] parts3 = parts2[1].split(":");
String ftp = parts3[0];
String port = parts3[1];
```

Do you have another solution?

Thank you :)

Comment: Well, you _could_ use a regex along with capturing groups (which might be optional) and get those. For doing this have a look at how to use `Pattern` and `Matcher`. - The regex itself could look like this (right off the top of my head so it might not be ideal and might contain errors - it should get you started though):`[^:]+://([^:]+):([^@])+@([^:]+):([^/]+)` - group 1 would be the user, group 2 the password, group 3 the domain and group 4 the port.

Comment: Sounds like you'd want to use [java.net.URI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html)

Comment: If you are new using regex you can try using this page https://regexr.com/ it helps a lot to understand how regex works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably not the cleanest way, but this is just with one split.

```
String fullFtpAddress = "ftp://user:password@ftp.domain.com:21";
String[] parts = fullFtpAddress.split("[:,@,/]");
String domain = parts[5];
String user = parts[3];
String password = parts[4];
String port = parts[6];
```

Using Uri:

```
URI uri = URI.create(fullFtpAddress);
String domain = uri.getHost();
String userInfo = uri.getUserInfo();
String user = userInfo != null ? userInfo.split(":")[0] : null;    
String password = userInfo != null ? userInfo.split(":")[1]: null;
int port = uri.getPort();
```

Comment: This is the domain string

Comment: thank you Maxdola, i will use URI. that seems to be the best :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) fields:

```
URL url = new URL("ftp://user:password@ftp.domain.com:21");
String userInfo = url.getUserInfo();
String protocol = url.getProtocol();
String host = url.getHost();
int port = url.getPort();
...
```

Comment: This is only partly what he asked for.

Comment: @Maxdola as I entered the answer the earlier answer was already accepted; a link provided. Added some getters, but not all handled; userInfo can be null, and should be split in name and password.

Comment: Ok I see, userInfo can be null, but won't be null since he provided the url which has a userInfo.

Comment: @Maxdola yes. `String user = userInfo == null ? null : userInfo.split(":")[0];` - Still a split.